# How to Abort Current task in windows form application c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, task, abort

I want to provide a button which cancels the present task,

Let's say I want to perform the following task, which takes approximately 30 minutes

```
 private void CaptureSignal()
  {
        // Capture Signal Code ......
  }
```

I need to display a button which cancels the current task(any time during the process).

any suggestions...?

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: How are you launching / running this task ? Please provide the details/code.

Comment: If you run it using a BackgroundWorker, which you should if it takes 30 minutes, then that provides a Cancel method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your capture is done inside main thread, try this:

```
bool abort = false;

private void CaptureSignal()
{
    while (!abort) {
    {
        // Capture Signal Code ......
    }
}

private void OnButtonClick(.............)
{
    abort = true;
}
```

If you're using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58) you can send a cancellation request.

Comment: If you are running it in the main thread, the CaptureSignal method will block any other calls; you wont be able to click abort. 100% Agree with the BackgroundWorker suggestion though.

Comment: @dash: correct, but OP could call `Application.ProcessMessages()` inside `CaptureSignal`. It's ugly, but I've seen it many times around ;)

Comment: Thank you Marco, I'm running it on my main thread, what would be  the best if I want to have an abort button as a generic control, which cancels currently running task.